# Nextjs returns 404 on reload but works on localhost hosted on Vercel

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I have a nextjs project hosted on the vercel, and I am facing issue that when I reload some path (ex. `/blogs`) it returns `404`. But, when I first access to the path, there is no problem and just show exactly what I want.

Path that I want to access is `/blogs` and directory structure is simply as below.

```
pages
     - blogs.tsx
```

and my `blogs.tsx` are using `getStaticPros` to get all blog `mdx` files.

```
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import React from 'react'
import { Blogs } from '@component/blogs'
import BlogsType from '@src/types/blog'
import { getAllBlogs } from '@utils/blog/getAllPosts'

type BlogStaticInputs = {
    blogs: BlogsType[]
}

export const Index = ({ blogs }: BlogStaticInputs) => {
    return <Blogs blogs={blogs} />
}

// get all blogs data from './blogs'
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const blogs = getAllBlogs([
        'date',
        'description',
        'slug',
        'title',
        'author',
        'image',
        'sns',
        'username'
    ])

    return {
        props: { blogs },
        revalidate: 10
    }
}

export default Index
```

As I explained, it perfectly works on the first visit, but it fails on reload or after first visit on refresh.

I did some research and I found I should add `trailingSlash:true` on the next.config.js config file but it didn't solve my problem.

The error message is simpley `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`. I am wondering why this happens since it just works locally (localhost) but suddenly fails on vercel preview url.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `getAllBlogs` function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try building the app first on local environment via `npm run build` and check for blog.json file response in network tab because sometimes it does get 404 on .json file and still works that becomes problem on vercel later on.

Comment: I investigated vercel log and noticed `getStaticProps` is called when deployed first time - so it works when I visit the page first time. However, when I reload the page, it suddenly goes to 404 as if the page does not exist and it continues disappear after that.

Comment: What do the Vercel logs show after you reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue.
Removing the `revalidate` has solved it for me. For me i had revalidate every 36000 seconds, and i noticed my site was failing after exactly 10hours (36000s). For you it seems is 10 seconds, so you visit once, you get the cached files, and the second time nextjs tries to get the new data from the api.

Unfortunately I don't know why it fails, i just know that it will fix it. But you wont have ISR anymore you'll have just SSG.

I'll edit my answer once i find the culprit.
Hope it helps.